# Trying to calculate between 2 Table Queries based on date range

Tags: excel-formula, calculated-columns, powerquery

So I have an issue where I am trying to apply a calculation to data in each column of Table 1 in my "LP_Input" query incorporating the figure on Table 2 in my "MA_Input" query. The main issue is that the figures on Table 2 are based on date ranges identified in 2 columns "Start Date" "End Date" and the figure used changes over time so Client 1 may have 2 date ranges which use a different figure.

In excel the formula would look like this: =((1+C16)/((1+C173)^(1/12)))-1

Where C16 is the corresponding value in Table 1; matching date and client name with C173 from the Table 2.

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kIYy.png)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xanU0.png)

One of the options I played with was converting Table 2 to mimic the layout of Table 1 effectively generating the MA value against each month end date between the date range as an individual Cell. Then I could at least work some sort of custom column to calculate per client or perhaps use Powerpivot to do the calculations.

EDIT: See Below relation - That block of figures are related to that range of dates and as such need to utilise the yellow boxed figure in the calculation. 
The formula example was taken from the old method so my apologies the Cell Ref is a bit useless but as a translation to make more sense:

C16 = any of the figures in the block of data
C173 = this would be the yellow boxed figure

Therefore for every instance of C16 the calculation would need to be applied using the figure C173 as those C16 figure fall within the highlighted date range. Hopefully that's more useful.

[Example Data Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqGyP.png)

Comment: I don't think you are providing enough info.  There is no way to tell what C16 or C173 are in your images.   How doe the Date field in image 1 match up with Start and End Dates in image 2.  Can you provide a simple example tracing a row from image 1 to image 2 with all data visible?

Comment: Please see edits - does that help?